# Remove deep items from an object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm looking to remove the encapsulating object that `recipeStep` resides in that's equal to `heat`. So the first array items in `recipeMealSteps` would be removed as it contains `heat`.

I've tried using `.map` and `.filter`, but I'm not getting back the whole object minus the `heat` steps.

Here's what I've got so far that's failing:

```js
let filteredRecipes = meals.map((m) =>
  m.mealTypeRecipes.map((r) => r.recipeMealSteps.filter((s) => s.recipeStep !== 'heat'))
);

let meals = [
  {
    mealId: 0,
    mealDescription: "Favourties",
    mealTypeRecipes: [
      {
        recipeAuthor: "Frank Doe",
        recipeDescription: "Great chicken dish for those that don't eat chicken",
        recipeID: 0,
        recipeMealSteps: [
          {
            recipeDesc: "Heat up the oven",
            recipeStep: "heat",
          },
          {
            recipeDesc: "Allow it to cook",
            recipeStep: "cool",
          },
          {
            recipeDesc: "Take it out the oven",
            recipeStep: "out",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        recipeID: 1,
        recipeName: "Fish Dish",
        recipeMealSteps: [
          {
            recipeDesc: "Heat up the oven",
            recipeStep: "heat",
          },
          {
            recipeDesc: "Allow it to cook",
            recipeStep: "cool",
          },
          {
            recipeDesc: "Take it out the oven",
            recipeStep: "out",
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Comment: So you want to remove every recipeStep which equals to "heat" right ?

Comment: That's correct, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let filteredRecipes = meals.map(({mealTypeRecipes, ...m}) => ({
  ...m,
   mealTypeRecipes: mealTypeRecipes.map(({recipeMealSteps,...r}) => ({
     ...r, 
     recipeMealSteps: recipeMealSteps.filter((s) => s.recipeStep !== 'heat') 
    })
)}));
```

EDIT:

Explanation: in the first map, we get as a parameter of the callback function every meal item. We deconstruct it so that 'm' is an object with all properties 'mealTypeRecipes' (in this case, m has properties 'meadId' and 'mealDescription'). On the other hand we put in the variable  'mealTypeRecipes' the value of the property 'mealTypeRecipes'. This is done thanks to the spread operator "...". This would be equivalent

```
let filteredRecipes = meals.map((mealItem) => {
    const {mealTypeRecipes, ...m} = mealItem
```

Then we return the reconstructed object returning the new value for property "mealTypeRecipes" and putting it together we the part of the object we didn't modify, "...m". This creates a copy of the old object, ensuring immutability.

A more verbose way to do the same would be like this

```
let filteredRecipes = meals.map((meal) => {
  const {mealTypeRecipes, ...m} = meal;
  return {
    ...m,
     mealTypeRecipes: mealTypeRecipes.map((mealTypeRecipeItem) => {
       const {recipeMealSteps,...r} = mealTypeRecipeItem;
       return {
          ...r,
          recipeMealSteps: recipeMealSteps.filter((s) => s.recipeStep !== 'heat')    
       }
     })
    }
 });
```

Comment: I had attempted something vaguely similar with the spread operator in an attempt to merge the returned arrays with the original but didn't understand what was going on well enough to come to a correct conclusion. So, thank you - this works great!

Comment: I've been pouring over the code and am close to understanding it but could someone explain exactly what's going on.

Comment: @Mint_Sauce I explained it in the answer

Comment: @de3 Thank you, I *really* appreciate that you took the time to do that!